# Restoring a single application to a previous state without restoring the system entirely

Tags: macos, google-chrome, time-machine

On a Mac running OS 10.11.6 I mistakenly deleted some saved passwords in the Google Chrome app that I now need to recover. I have Time Machine backups that I can use to restore the system as a whole but that seems like overkill for this particular situation.

Can I restore a single application like Google Chrome to a previous state while leaving the rest of the system as it is?

Comment: If you answered the question and you feel your answer was the correct answer then why did you then delete the answer? Maybe it is the correct answer for the majority of people. What I said is that your answer didn't work for me. But if you feel it is the correct answer, then by deleting the answer, you are doing a disservice to all who might encounter this same problem in the future.

Comment: And then you also delete your comments as well. Very mature and rational decision making. Well, now I'm glad that you also decided to trivially edit my question so there is at least some record of your involvement and the insanity that resulted from it. @techraf - please feel free to never answer any question I ask again. Good day sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover single files and folders with Time Machine - just open it from /Applications or Launchpad, navigate to a specific folder, choose time and click "Restore". The passwords should be either in ~/Library/Keychains or in Chrome's profile folder (sorry, I don't have this browser to check where is it).